# How to use touchstart and touchend events to track click on a cross domain iframe on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, touch-event

I just figured out how to detect click event on a cross domain iframe but it's only working for desktop, the following code works when detecting the click event inside the iframe, however, I also need it to work on mobile devices, I tried to use the `touchstart`and `touchend`events to add mobile support to this script, but it's not working.

```
 //Google ADs track conversion
$( document ).ready(function() { 

        var iframeMouseOver = false;
        var iframeTouched = false;
        $("#wh-widget-send-button")
            .off("mouseover.iframe").on("mouseover.iframe", function() {
                iframeMouseOver = true;
            })
            .off("mouseout.iframe").on("mouseout.iframe", function() {
                iframeMouseOver = false;
            });

        //Add mobile support to this script
        $("#wh-widget-send-button")
            .off("touchstart").on("touchstart", function() {
                iframeTouched = true;
            })
            .off("touchend").on("touchend", function() {
                iframeTouched = false;
            });

        $(window).off("blur.iframe").on("blur.iframe", function() {
            if(iframeMouseOver || iframeTouched){
                 console.log("Iframe Clicked");
                 gtag_report_conversion();
            }
        });
});
```

### UPDATE

The HTML as requested, it's just a simple iframe inside a div, also cleared the above code a bit to focus on the important part:

```
<div id="wh-widget-send-button">
  <iframe src="http://anyexternaldomain.com"></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: Can I include HTML as well?

Comment: If you want you can make a jsfiddle with your answer

Comment: Sorry. I meant can you include HTML?

Comment: @KalimahApps done check again

Comment: thanks. I am not sure how much interaction you need with the iframe. Would it be just a click over the iframe or you need interaction with certain elements inside iframe?

Comment: The iframe is just a whatsapp button, so I would just need to get any click inside the iframe on mobile, make sure it works with cross domain as the example.

Comment: Is it working for you? I was looking for something similar... Are you able to accurately get touch as well as mouse clicks captured from Iframes

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure why you need to check for hover or touch. You can just check for click and perform the action.

The main concept is to remove event handling from iframe by assigning `pointer-events:none;`. This will make the parent element `wh-widget-send-button` receive all events and then you can handle them as needed.

You can try this code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#wh-widget-send-button").off("click").on("click", function() {
    console.log("Clicked");
   // gtag_report_conversion();
  });
});
```

```css
iframe
{
   pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wh-widget-send-button">
  <iframe src="http://anyexternaldomain.com"></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: The problem with this code is that while it does "work" in the sense that it detects clicks on the iframe, it makes it impossible to interact with anything in the iframe, which I assume is why the OP said it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, what you are trying to do is impossible. The developers of web browsers have purposefully made it so, in order to avoid the malicious practice of clickjacking. You cannot catch a click that goes into an iframe. What you are currently doing on desktop is only tracking whether the mouse hovers over the iframe, not whether it is actually clicked. Unfortunately, you cannot do even this on mobile, because the touch on the touchscreen is automatically transmitted to the iframe, there is no such concept as "hover" as it applies to touch screens. Sorry to drop bad news on you.